# Manipulação de imagem com nodejs e ionic

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, rest, ionic3

Tenho um aplicativo Ionic, nele tenho que enviar uma imagem convertida para base64 para uma api, e da api para o banco de dados. Eu estava obtendo erro pelo tamanho do payload, encontrei na internet sobre utilizar o JSON.stringfy, aparentemente deu certo, porém, não consigo receber na API e armazenar no banco de dados. Segue os códigos utilizados:

Para realizar a conversão :

```
getPhoto() {
    let options = {
      maximumImagesCount: 1
    };
    this.imagePicker.getPictures(options).then((results) => {
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
          this.imgPreview = results[i];
          this.base64.encodeFile(results[i]).then((base64File: string) => {
            this.regData.avatar = base64File;
            this.novoCredenciadoModel.caminho = this.regData.avatar;
          }, (err) => {
            console.log(err);
          });
      }
    }, (err) => { });
  }
```

Para enviar para o provider:

```
register() {
    this.novoCredenciadoService.enviar(this.novoCredenciadoModel).subscribe((result) => {
      // this.loading.dismiss();
      let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: 'Registration Successful',
        subTitle: 'Great! Your registration is success',
        buttons: ['OK']
      });
      alert.present();
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
      // this.loading.dismiss();
      let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: 'Registration Failed',
        subTitle: 'Oh no! Your registration is failed',
        buttons: ['OK']
      });
      alert.present();
    });
  }
```

E no provider:

```
return this.http.post(Constants.CAMINHO_TESTE+api,JSON.stringify(corpoRequisicao))
    .pipe(map((resp: Response) =>{
      console.log(JSON.stringify(corpoRequisicao));
      console.log("post/response");
      console.log (resp);
      }));
```

Na API, o seguinte, para receber os dados:

```
var received = JSON.stringify(req);

var nome = received.nome;
var email = received.email;
var telefone = received.telefone;
var endereco = received.endereco;
var cnpj = received.cnpj;
var categoria = received.categoria;
var caminho = received.caminho; //caminho seria a img em base64
```

Porém obtenho o seguinte erro:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token P in JSON at position 0

Alguma forma de realizar tal função?

Edit:

```
 handler: () => {
            this.http.post("minharota/api/novo", JSON.stringify(postData), requestOptions)
              .subscribe(data => {
```

O Postdata são os dados que vem do formulario, que acho que estão corretos porque quando loguei foi normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Você precisa passar a imagem para um endpoint independente para o upload via sua api. Ex.: POST /api/uploadimage .
2. A chave necessária no seu header para a requisição:

   - Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
   - Body: um parametro com algum nome (exemplo: image) e o valor desse seria a imagem em base64
3. Na sua rota na API Node: (existem outras formas de fazer isso, muitas até mais elegantes)

   ```
   var imageEncoding = req.body.image.replace(/ /g, "+");
   ```

   Variavel imageEncoding pode ser salva em um campo varchar, string, etc.
4. Não esqueça de configurar sua api para receber conteúdo via requisição maiores, se for o seu caso.

   Exemplo com Node e Express:

   ```
   app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true, limit: '50mb'}));
   app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
   ```
5. Se você não utiliza alguma ferramenta para testes de comunicação com Rest APIs, sugiro que use alguma (a comunidade usa muito o postman), pois são mais minimalistas e fazem você ganhar tempo com esses testes.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Realizando esse imageEncoding, vou conseguir depois mostrar a imagem no app normalmente ou teria que realizar algum decoding especifico ?

Comment: Conseguiria sim e não necessita de um decoding. Isso "req.body.image.replace(/ /g, "+");" é necessário para tratar o conteúdo que foi transformado pelo "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" durante a requisição.

Comment: Eu estava testando aqui, e me deparei com o seguinte cenário: Se eu não uso  ali o bodyparser pra aumentar o limite, ele dá payload to large, OK. Porém se eu uso, ele diz que a imagem vem undefined, e da erro no parse. Fiz exatamente como você recomendou, será que ficou algo pra trás ?

Comment: Envie por favor o código do Request que está sendo disparado para a sua api?

Comment: editei a pergunta, coloquei no final

Comment: 1. a imagem deve não pode ser passada como json. Ela deve ser passada assim, supondo que o nome do parâmetro seja image: image=imagemEmBase64

Comment: 2. O único parâmetro que deve ser enviado é o da imagem
3. Não pode esquecer de passar no Header: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: exemplo de uma mensagem HTTP para essa finalidade:

PUT /api/users/alterarImagem HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3000
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIwNjYuMjcwLjI5Ni00MiJ9.9lX3rMFi42EI1zmRcLzalw_S874NJ7dAK8_MS66BOMQ
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: afe76ca1-d3c1-6eb6-bd1c-4c20d1e47da9

image=/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEBLAE ...

Comment: Primeiro use o Postman, garanta que a troca de mensagem HTTP funciona e depois você implementa na tecnologia que desejar